# kohana htaccess and index structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana

I am using kohana 3.2

My site is www.mysite.com/best, kohana is installed on best.

I am using the default htaccess file with rewritebase /best

so what is the best way to redirect users that go to www.mysite.com?

Right now if someone puts www.mysite.com/helo (www.mysite.com/best/helo)
It loads but apache gives 404 not found.

I hope my question makes sense.

> **EDIT**

If a user goes to main domain (www.mysite.com) I want it to load kohana located at mysite/best. 
but if a user right now types the full thing and omits best, site will load but my forms wont work because it is posting to www.mysite.com/helo not www.mysite.com/best/helo
instead of loading the fake helo controller, it must show a page not found.

> EDIT

Ok I added this to htaccess file and it works perfectly

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/best/
```

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /best/$1`

Comment: give us your full .htaccess file.  does loading www.mysite.com/best work?  does www.mysite.com/best/index.php/helo work?

Comment: It is the standard htaccess file that comes in kohana. yes, both work. If a user puts www.mysite.com it shows a list of folders no index.html is loaded. if they put www.mysite.com/best it loads kohana index.php. Now if they use it with a controller so and best is omited it works, but the title and the headers in firebug say PAGE NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple rewritebase in htaccess so... 
rewrite your rules to fit you need in /best 
or put an other htaccess in / to rewrite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess instead:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /best/

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
#RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT,L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Note that the trailing / on RewriteBase is required.